# MVEL2 on android throws exception

Tags: android, mvel

Did anyone has experience with MVEL2 on android?

i've tried out the same code with a simple java program and later on android:

The following exception is thrown when executed on android:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30793): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I tried the example from the mvel website:

```
String template = "Hello, my name is @{name.toUpperCase()}";
Map vars = new HashMap();
vars.put("name", "Michael");
System.out.println(TemplateRuntime.eval(template, vars));
```

If theres no solution could anyone suggest a template engine which works with android
and supports iteration?

Answer (score 5):

MVEL2 tries to substring the first 3 characters of the system java.version property when initializing the parser, and under Android the version is 0. That causes a bunch of exceptions which eventually cause the ExceptionInInitializerError.

If you want to force the java.version property, you can simply set it yourself:

```
System.setProperty("java.version", "1.6");
```

I have no idea what kind of odd side effects this may cause for Android, but at least it gets the MVEL parser up and running without throwing exceptions!

Comment: If you are worried about side-effects, try reseting the property back. Like this. 
`String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version"); System.setProperty("java.version", "1.6");
doCodeHere();System.setProperty("java.version", javaVersion);`

Answer (score 1):

System.setProperty with "java.version" key seems to be read only propery in android, so it won't work.
i've tried to integrate MVEL 2 into android with no success, [try using EVAL lib](https://java.net/projects/eval/pages/Home%20EVAL)